# How to add numbers to even and odd lists in java?

Tags: java

I want to make a program that will read from the keyboard a sequence of numbers and
will create a dynamic list of even numbers and another dynamic list of odd numbers, and I have a problem, the even numbers are added to the even list and the odd ones to the odd list, but the display does not display the numbers I added.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class lab13_1 {
static  ArrayList<lab13_1> odd = new ArrayList<>();
static  ArrayList<lab13_1> even = new ArrayList<>();
static int number;
public lab13_1(int number) {
    this.number=number;
}
public String toString()
{
    return "number"+number;
}


static void calc() {
try {
Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);


System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to add : ");
int nr = cin.nextInt();
for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
    System.out.println("<<< nr. " + (i + 1) + " >>>");

     number = cin.nextInt();
    if (number % 2 == 0) {
        even.add(new lab13_1(number));
    } else odd.add(new lab13_1(number));

}


 } catch (Exception e) {
e.printStackTrace();
 }

}

static void afish(){

    System.out.println("Nr. odd");
    for(lab13_1 i : odd) {
        System.out.println(i.toString());
    }
    System.out.println("Nr. even");
    for(lab13_1 i : even) {
        System.out.println(i.toString());
    }
}

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

   calc();
  afish();
}
```

}

the data it displays :

```
How many numbers do you want to add :
5
<<< nr. 1 >>>
1
<<< nr. 2 >>>
2
<<< nr. 3 >>>
3
<<< nr. 4 >>>
4
<<< nr. 5 >>>
5
Nr. odd
number5
number5
number5
Nr. even
number5
number5
```

Who knows why it doesn't display numbers normally?

Comment: `static int number` - here is your problem. Variable is static which means that all instances of that class share the same value. Remove the `static` keyword. After that you will need to add a new local variable inside of `calc` function to store the input in place of `number`.

Comment: Btw. please follow Java naming convention - class names start with an uppercase letter.

Answer (score 2):

It's because your variable `number` is static. Remove `static` keyword and it should be fine.

```
int number;
```

Comment: As I pointed out in the comment to the question, OP will need to add a variable inside of `calc` function in place of `number` - it's worth adding to the answer. Plus maybe some explanation why `static` causes the problem

Answer (score 1):

You are using a static variable.
Static means that it does not depend by the instance of the class..
Usually you use static variables for counting the instances of an object or the nr. of times a function is called.
For e.g.

```
class TestStatic
{
    public static int count = 0;
    int mNumber;

    void doSomething(int number)
    {
        mNumber=number;
        count++;
    }
    int getNumber()
    {
        return mNumber;
    }
}
```

Using it

```
public static void main()
{
    List<TestStatic> tsList = new ArrayList<TestStatic>();
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
    {
        TestStatic ts = new TestStatic();
        ts.doSomething(i); 
        tsList.add(ts);        
    }
    for(TestList ts : tsList)
    {
        System.out.println("Count = " + ts.count + "mynumber = " + ts.getNumber() );
    }

}
```

In the output you will see count always at 5, number 0,1,2,3,4
This should let you explain how to use static variables.

Note that you should access static variables with

```
TestStatic.count
```

not with the instance.

P.S. code should run but i've not tested it

Answer (score 0):

This is a cleaner answer to your desired goal

```
public class lab13_1 {
    static ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<>();
    static ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<>();
    static int number;

    static void calc() {
        try {
            Scanner cin = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("How many numbers do you want to add : ");
            int nr = cin.nextInt();
            for (int i = 0; i < nr; i++) {
                System.out.println("<<< nr. " + (i + 1) + " >>>");

                number = cin.nextInt();
                if (number % 2 == 0) {
                    even.add(number);
                } else odd.add(number);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    static void afish() {
        System.out.println("Nr. odd");
        for (Integer i : odd) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
        System.out.println("Nr. even");
        for (Integer i : even) {
            System.out.println(i.toString());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        calc();
        afish();
    }
}
```